# Optaplanner : Initializing planning variable problem

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am new to Optaplanner and to get familiar with it I tried to run a simple code.
The idea is I have one single planning variable of type integer, that has a range between 1 and 30, that I try to maximize. So normally the solver should give me a value of 30.

My code is as follows :

**Planning entity and planning variable :**

```
@PlanningEntity
public class variable {

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "xRange")
    private Integer x;

    public variable() {

    }   

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Integer x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    
}
```

**Planning solution**

@PlanningSolution
public class Planningsolution {

```
@PlanningEntityProperty
private variable variable;

@ValueRangeProvider(id="xRange")
public CountableValueRange<Integer> getxRange(){
    return ValueRangeFactory.createIntValueRange(1, 30);
}

@PlanningScore
private HardSoftScore score;

public Planningsolution() {

}

public variable getVariable() {
    return variable;
}

public void setVariable(variable variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
}

public HardSoftScore getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
    this.score = score;
}
```

}

**Constraint Provider**

```
public class SimpleConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {


    
     @Override
        public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return new Constraint[] {
                    // Hard constraints
                    maxValue(constraintFactory),

            };
     }
            
         private Constraint maxValue (ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
                
                return constraintFactory.forEach(variable.class)
                        .reward("maximum", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,variable::getX);
                    }
}
```

**Main :**

```
public class SimpleApp {

     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleApp.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SolverFactory<Planningsolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
                    .withSolutionClass(Planningsolution.class)
                    .withEntityClasses(variable.class)
                    .withConstraintProviderClass(SimpleConstraintProvider.class)

                    .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(10)));

            // Load the problem
            Planningsolution problem = new Planningsolution();
            
            

            // Solve the problem
            Solver<Planningsolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
            Planningsolution solution = solver.solve(problem);

            // Visualize the solution
           System.out.println("solution: " + display(solution) + "\n" + "score: " + solution.getScore());;
        }
    
        
        public static Integer display(Planningsolution solution) {
            variable var = new variable();
            return var.getX();
        }
}
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.optaplanner" level="info"/>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="appender"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

The output i get is :

> solution: null
> score: 0hard/0soft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for planning variables to be initializable, they must be able to accept `null` as a value. Java primitive types (such as `int`) are not capable of doing that, therefore your planning variable needs to be an `Integer`. The error message even tells you to do that, although the wording is a bit cryptic.

As a side note, I think we should be able to handle this situation better. If people don't want `null` in there, we should not force them. Something to consider for future development.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed fixes my initialization problem. I did run the program and it returns a value 'null'. Which means that the solver did not solve the problem (Even the score show 0hard/0soft).  What should I do in this situation ?

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code and include output of the program.

Comment: When I say outptut, I mean the logging output; not the solution, the actual system output. To understand, what the solver did or did not do, I'll need to see the scroll.

Comment: Well I didn't get any log, maybe because the solver didn't run ?? Either way, when I run the program all I get as an output is the solution. (I updated the question with the logback.xml I used)

Comment: In that case, please share the code that you used to run OptaPlanner. Because what you're describing here really sounds like you did not run it.

Comment: The code I used to run OptaPlanner is the one in the main method (public class SimpleApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) { ....). I have put my project in this github link  : https://github.com/usumake1/testing-optaplanner

Comment: Basically I got inspired by the timetable example, I wrote the code and it run perfectly. then I wanted to see if I can run a simple code from scratch. Which resulted in the code above.

Comment: Hello, I got the logging output : 
2022-08-27 10:27:43,964 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (100), best score (0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2022-08-27 10:27:43,975 [main] INFO  Skipped all phases (2): out of 0 planning entities, none are movable (non-pinned).
2022-08-27 10:27:43,983 [main] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (113), best score (0hard/0soft), score calculation speed (8/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).

Comment: That should already tell you what the issue is. Your problem seems to have no entities. In fact, looking at your SimpleApp, you never assign any value to the single entity field. Therefore there is nothing for OptaPlanner to do.

Comment: Thank you, it was looking at me the whole time. It's running fine now.